# How are our tastes created?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, aesthetics, preferences

Is there a scientific explanation of one's aesthetic preferences? Why do they differ from one person to another? Are they the results of one's culture and social interactions?

Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the main theories that account for why some people like X and others not?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/10410/what-are-the-main-theories-that-account-for-why-some-people-like-x-and-others-no)