# What makes you like someone?

Tags: social-psychology, perception, personality, sensory-perception

Everyone has some friends and some people, you can't get along with.
But what makes them different?

Is it smell, the voice, attractiveness, the way they express themselves, their sence of humor?

I can try, as hard as I want, to like some people, but they appeal just not sympathic to me. I'ts not that they are bad people or mean and I can have a good conversation with them, but somehow, I just don't like them.

I know, liking someone is highly subjective, but this is exactely my question!
Which factors decide upon, whether you like someone or not.

And how can it be that some people are generally liked and disliked?
What is their factor?

This is not a duplicate of [What makes people like other people?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/16441/14541), which is asking for group behaviour. I would like to know, what makes an Individual likable or not.

I'd much rather have a list of factoras as an Answer than an explanation (the explanation is asked for in the previously mentioned question).

In other words, "what makes someone likable"?